# How to test for additional properties of expected Exceptions using ScalaTest

Tags: exception, testing, scala, scalatest

I'm using ScalaTest for testing some Scala code.
I currently testing for expected exceptions with code like this

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers

class ImageComparisonTest extends FeatureSpec with ShouldMatchers{

    feature("A test can throw an exception") {

        scenario("when an exception is throw this is expected"){
            evaluating { throw new Exception("message") } should produce [Exception]
        }
    }
}
```

But I would like to add additional check on the exception, e.g. I would like to check that the exceptions message contains a certain String.

Is there a 'clean' way to do this? Or do I have to use a try catch block?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found a solution

```
val exception = intercept[SomeException]{ ... code that throws SomeException ... }
// you can add more assertions based on exception here
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do the same sort of thing with the evaluating ... should produce syntax, because like intercept, it returns the caught exception:

```
val exception =
  evaluating { throw new Exception("message") } should produce [Exception]
```

Then inspect the exception.

Comment: It works and I like this syntax: it's in line with all of the "should be" for function results.

Comment: `evaluating` is deprecated in 2.x and removed in 3.x. Deprecation docs advise using `an [Exception] should be thrownBy` instead. However 3.0.0-M14 returns an `Assertion`: `val ex: Assertion = an [Exception] should be thrownBy {throw new Exception("boom")}`. Is there a way to get back the `Exception` thrown?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to further inspect an expected exception, you can capture it using this syntax:

```
val thrown = the [SomeException] thrownBy { /* Code that throws SomeException */ }
```

This expression returns the caught exception so that you can inspect it further:

```
thrown.getMessage should equal ("Some message")
```

you can also capture and inspect an expected exception in one statement, like this:

```
the [SomeException] thrownBy {
  // Code that throws SomeException
} should have message "Some message"
```

Comment: This nicely follows existing non-exception test patterns. Awesome.